# Self service password for open ldap using docker

Tags: dockerfile

I want to configure the self-service password for LDAP using Docker.
I am working on MacOSX and I have successfully configured the open LDAP server on ubuntu 14.04 using VMware fusion and I am trying to configure the ssp on docker. But my connection is not happening.
The error is coming as Can not connect to LDAP directory please help me in that.

Comment: What's that error saying?

Comment: Cannot access LDAP directory
I got the UI of self service password but when I am entering the uid and password its showing cant access the LDAP directory